# PsExec running PowerShell cmdlets with spaces in the arguments

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to use PsExec to run Expand-Archive on a remote computer, extracting to a folder inside Program Files, but Expand-Archive keeps returning the error:

```
Expand-Archive : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files\Folder'
```

I take this to mean that Expand-Archive gets to the space in "Program Files" and thinks one argument is done and starts trying to interpret the next.

I have used the following variants of the command, all with the same outcome:

Double-quotes around entire Powershell portion, using %programfiles% environment variable:

```
.\PsExec.exe \\computername /s cmd /c "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command expand-archive c:\temp\bc.zip -destinationpath %programfiles%\Folder"
```

Single-quotes just around the destination folder path, using %programfiles% environment variable:

```
.\PsExec.exe \\computername /s cmd /c C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command expand-archive c:\temp\bc.zip -destinationpath '%programfiles%\Folder'
```

Double-quotes just around the destination folder path, using %programfiles% environment variable:

```
.\PsExec.exe \\computername /s cmd /c C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command expand-archive c:\temp\bc.zip -destinationpath "%programfiles%\Folder"
```

No quotes, using %programfiles% environment variable:

```
.\PsExec.exe \\computername /s cmd /c C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command expand-archive c:\temp\bc.zip -destinationpath %programfiles%\Folder
```

Double-quotes around fully typed folder path:

```
.\PsExec.exe \\computername /s cmd /c C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command expand-archive c:\temp\bc.zip -destinationpath "C:\Program Files\Folder"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried doing the same with psexec, and i'm facing all kinds of errors.

I would personally use powershell's invoke command. Would this also work for you? If not i will try to fiddle with psexec some more if you would like.

Example :

$PATH = "EnterPath"

$COMPUTERNAME = "EnterComputerName"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $COMPUTERNAME -ScriptBlock {

```
    $DESTINATIONPATH = $env:ProgramFiles
    Expand-Archive -Path $using:PATH -DestinationPath $DESTINATIONPATH
```

}

The script will run on given computer, $env:ProgramFiles translates to the variable on the remote computer, equivalent of %programfiles% in cmd.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. For testing I turned it into a one-liner: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer -ScriptBlock { Expand-Archive -path C:\temp\bc.zip -DestinationPath "$env:ProgramFiles\folder"}`. It also appears to continue to work across network interruptions, which is something PsExec doesn't handle as neatly.

Comment: Among other suggestions, I found this on SE which attempts to solve the quotes issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961857/psexec-pass-argument-with-spaces-for-powershell But I'm looking for the solution that works, not the "perfect" solution. Knowing how to make PsExec function with awkward arguments is good, but I can work on that at some later time.

Comment: You're all seemingly barking up the wrong tree, it's not issue with PSExec at all. I am running this same Powershell command in my own system and I am getting the same error, which I mustn't get because I've used quotes for allowing spaces in path which should be more than enough. The command: `powershell Expand-Archive "%%~nI.zip" "%%~nI"` (%%I is coming just find from parent for-loop), the supposed correct folder name "F1 F2" and the error I am getting is `Expand-Archive : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'F1'`, it breaks at the part of folder name before space

Comment: And hurray !! I just solved this with couple small changes like this: `powershell "& Expand-Archive \"%%~nI.zip\" \"%%~nI\""` and it works like charm now !!. Seems sometimes we are forced to enclose powershell commands in quotes and apply ampersand& in prior position and also escape the inner quotes of command

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that the accepted answer is not correct, but rather it's not targeting the actual issue in my opinion.

Here there's not any issue with `PSExec`, but issue with how the `PowerShell` command is called.

When calling Powershell command many a times we cannot just pass commands without quotes, especially those commands that need quoted arguments like *spaced-paths* of OS directory structure. So we have to apply ampersand `&` before command when calling the command and escape the command's inner quotes for arguments, which pretty much looks like this:

```
powershell "& Expand-Archive \"<filepathwithspaces>\" \"<targetfolderpathwithspaces>\""
```

OR

```
.\PsExec.exe \\computername /s cmd /c C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command "& expand-archive c:\temp\bc.zip -destinationpath \"C:\Program Files\Folder\""
```

You can also ignore the `-command` switch in the above one-liner as long as you provide `&` properly before actual command :)